# The support function in ODE-PDE comparison principle of Ricci flow

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, ricci-flow, support-function

Recent days, I want to understand the  ODE-PDE comparison principle of Ricci flow which is origin from the Hamilton's paper *Four-manifolds with positive curvature operator*.  But the Hamilton's paper has relatively much typos. Therefore, I turn to the Cao and Zhu's *A complete proof of the Poincare and geometrization conjectures*. But I also got stuck.

The picture below is from the Cao and Zhu's paper.  I have two basic problem about the support function.

(1) First, I don't know the mean of $|l|=1$. Obviously, it is not absolute. I guess it is the norm of $l$. But I am not sure. Besides, the definition of support function is really not similar to [what I used to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function).  Are they different words for the same thing?

(2) Second, what is the linear function of length one? I know what is linear function, but I don't know what is the length one.

**PS(2022-7-24):**   After some find, I think the $|l|=1$ and the length one  mean that $||l||=1$.   If you have same problem, you can read the Appendix B of *A complete proof of the differentiable 1/4-pinching sphere theorem*.  Although, they are not same. But from this book, I think it is $||l||=1$.

> [image]

> [image]
> [image]